# INSTANCE singleton missing

Tags: java, pac4j

I would like to add SSO functionalty to an existing Webapp and I am
trying to use pac4j for that. I downloaded the jee-jac4j-demo and
I am running in errors all over the place which all point to missing
static fields called "INSTANCE"

For example:

src/main/webapp/loginForm.jsp line 5:

```
  FormClient formClient = (FormClient) Config.INSTANCE.getClients().findClient("FormClient").get();
```

gives me the error:

```
Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [5] in the jsp file: [/loginForm.jsp]
INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field
5:  FormClient formClient = (FormClient) Config.INSTANCE.getClients().findClient("FormClient").get();
```

According the javadocs this field went away around version 6.0.0-RC2.

So here my questions:

- Is there a documentation/migration guide of the changes between 5.7.x and 6.0.x?
- What is the stand-in replacement for INSTANCE?
- Can this be fixed by altering the pom.xml? I tried to guess an alder version pac4j-code=5.7.0 jee-pac4j=7.1.0 but then I found this code inside ForceLoginFilter:

```
action = client.getRedirectionAction(new CallContext(context, JEESessionStore.INSTANCE)).get();
```

CallContext only seems to exist in pac4j 6.0, but JEESessionStore.INSTANCE is gone there?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fully right. There was an issue.

Using singletons is not generally the best practice so I removed it.

In plain JEE, it is still necessary though so the singleton is back in the `ConfigFactory` this time. It's fixed by this commit: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/commit/810da2c224f18f4a7bc44e1f34993cf992ddaf9b